Здравствуйте, не могу вытянуть элемент html
При парсинге, отсутствует блок div(класса нет), если смотреть на детей родительского элемента (<div class="middle-info-wrapper main_item_wrapper">). Но при просмотре через консоль разработчика(f12), он есть. Что это может быть и как это обойти.
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
html = `<div class="product-main">
    <div class="product-info-headnote clearfix" >
        <div class="flexbox flexbox--row align-items-center justify-content-between flex-wrap">
            <div class="preview-text">
                <div class="font_xs text-block">Кэш-память HP Smart Array 2GB, 631681-B21</div>
                <div class="flexbox flexbox--row flex-wrap align-items-normal">
                    <div class="product-action flex-50">
                        <div class="info_item">
                            <div class="middle-info-wrapper main_item_wrapper">
                                <div id="bxdynamic_qepX1R_start" style="display:none"></div>
                                <div class=""> 
                                    <div class="prices_block">
                                        <div class="cost prices detail">
                                            <div class="price_matrix_wrapper ">
                                                <div class="price font-bold font_mxs" data-currency="RUB"
                                                    data-value="16367.52">
                                                    <span class="values_wrapper"><span class="price_value">16
                                                        368</span><span class="price_currency"> ₽</span></span><span
                                                            class="price_measure">/шт</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="price_dol">
                                            <div class="txt1">172$</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="js-services"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div> `;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const priceValue = $("div.product-main").find('div.middle-info-wrapper.main_item_wrapper').find('span.price_value').text().trim();```
Скопировал html к себе, чтобы добраться до 'span.price_value'


значит добавляется динамически. Возможно во время парсинга этих данных нет, а затем, после получения данных уже формируются дочерние элементы данного div

Уже пробовал делать задержку setTimeout, но не помогло

https://andrejsabrickis.medium.com/scrapping-the-content-of-single-page-application-spa-with-headless-chrome-and-puppeteer-d040025f752b тут похожую проблему решают.

Спасибо, тогда попробую так сделать
